# exception when check if an element exists in a frame

Tags: frame, watir, watir-webdriver

When I try to check whether a element exists in a frame, but actually it doesn't, `watir` raise a exception.

```
> main_frame.exist?
=> true
> main_frame.table(:id => "Table_1").exist?
=> true
> main_frame.table(:id => "Table_2").exist?
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError: Element belongs to a different frame than the current one - switch to its containing frame to use it
    from [remote server] resource://fxdriver/modules/web_element_cache.js:5634:in `unknown'
    from [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20120531-5558-h7vd7r/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:5329:in `unknown'
    from [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20120531-5558-h7vd7r/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:6623:in `unknown'
    from [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20120531-5558-h7vd7r/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:9924:in `unknown'
    from [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20120531-5558-h7vd7r/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:9929:in `unknown'
    from [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20120531-5558-h7vd7r/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:9875:in `unknown'
    from /home/raincole/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in `assert_ok'
    from /home/raincole/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
    from /home/raincole/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `new'
...
```

But... shouldn't it return `false`? Why exception?

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me: https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/issues

Comment: I would tend to agree..  sample html and code would be appreciated just to be sure (and are useful for creating a new spec to test for this if one is needed